# How can I get wine to work on my amd64 computer?

Tags: 12.10, wine, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Wine on 64 Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit)

I am new to Ubuntu, and want to install Wine on my laptop. However, there only seem to be 32-bit packages. Could anyone tell me how to get Wine running? Although I am new to Linux, I am fairly tech-savvy - I want to use notepad++ in Wine to edit my website - and NO I don't want to use gedit or any other editor!

Comment: Richard: I suggest vim. It's very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Its really just a case of `sudo apt-get install wine` honest.

Comment: need more specifics such as the version of wine 1.4 or 1.5

Comment: @RickGreen-Turbo Why?, it would  be completely irrelevant to the question. If he sticks to the Ubuntu standard he will have wine 1.4 installed on his 64 bit Ubuntu machine on which he can install notepad++

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit not really going to matter any way