# Unable To Install Wine

Tags: installation, command-line, 12.10, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Wine on 64 Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit)

I am trying to install Wine 1.5, but I keep getting errors. I am trying to install via terminal. I have Ubuntu 12.10 x64. Here are the steps I have took all in order.

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa**

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Welcome to the Wine Team PPA.  Here you can get the latest available Wine betas for every supported version of Ubuntu.  This PPA is managed by Scott Ritchie and Maarten Lankhorst.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplm7whr/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplm7whr/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmplm7whr/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F9CB8DB0: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

**sudo apt-get update**

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease 
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release [49.6 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                 
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages [60.0 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages                       
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages                      
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe amd64 Packages [20.7 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages                  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,150 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en                  
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages [149 kB]   
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1,970 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [131 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US         
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7,936 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 473 kB in 21s (22.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

**sudo apt-get install wine1.5**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.19-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-droid
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

I would REALLY appreciate help, as I need Wine for a couple sales quota tracking software which are Windows Native. And a couple games.

Comment: wine 1.4 is not good? is already in the repository

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need some libraries to run 32-bit applications. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

After that try to install again. If it still does not work, try to run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```