# Install wine1.6-amd64 from ubuntu-wine ppa asked for installing wine1.6-i386 as well

Tags: wine, 64-bit, dependencies

When installing wine1.6 and wine1.6-amd64 from ppa:ubuntu-wine on Kubuntu 12.10 (quantal), it always asked me for installing wine1.6-i386

```
root@ezgo64:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# LC_ALL=C apt-get install wine1.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1.6-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@ezgo64:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# LC_ALL=C apt-get install wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1.6-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However, how could I install wine1.6-i386 on a amd64 box?  Therefore I need to download the package, extract it and change the dependency to remove wine1.6-i386 so that I can install this amd64 version of wine1.6.

wine1.5 has the same problem.

Any suggestions?

new information added:
Thanks for suggestions.  However when I tried to install wine1.6-i386, it asked for a lot of other i386 packages like libgstreamer0.10-0:i386. I was not able to install it and didn't know how to solve such dependencies. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Additional information: using this ppa repository I couldn't get wine1.6-i386 installed, even using dpkg --add-architecture i386 as this answer suggested: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit?rq=1

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Also check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install wine (or ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer... at least a solution.

[Can't install wine (or ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit?rq=1)

Using /etc/apt/preferences to assign Pin-Priority would solve the dependencies problems while installing wine-i386.  However, in some of my machines it would remove *almost all* kde packages and I need to re-install them back after installing i386 packages.

Comment: And some ppa would create this dependency problem  too.  I need to remove kubuntu backports ppa to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add additional architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

update your apt sources and it should work.

Example (as root):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 # Add i386 architecture for Wine
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa  # Add PPA/Wine repository
apt-get update
apt-get install -qy wine1.8
```

See also: [Can't install wine (or ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/q/210054/78223)

Answer (score 0):

The `wine1.x` metapackage depends on both `wine1.x-amd64` and `wine1.x-i386` actual packages. These correspond to support for amd64 and i386 *windows* applications. 64 bit systems can still run 32 bit binaries providing they have 32 bit versions of all the necessary libraries.

You can install only the `wine1.x-amd64` package to avoid the multiarch dependency, but you will then not be able to load 32-bit windows applications, which still seems to cover a significant fraction of games and applications.

I'm not sure about the dependency problems, but I would look for general fixing broken package answers rather than anything wine-specific.

Comment: as I have said in additional information above, there are a lot i386 dependencies needed to install wine1.6-i386.  Should I solve all these dependencies?