# unmet dependencies while installing wine

Tags: apt, wine, software-installation

Hello I am new here and I have been trying to install wine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1.7.4-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what should I do ?

Comment: You're trying to install a latest version of wine! Are you sure this version is in your repository? Did you add a new repository to install the latest version of wine? like: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` ? Reply..

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/176889

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `apt-cache policy wine1.7 wine1.7-i386`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow these steps to install wine1.7**

- open terminal and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install wine1.7
  ```

  if again last command gives you some error then replace it by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wine1.7 wine1.7-i386"=1.7.4-0ubuntu4"
  ```
- It should successfully install wine without any problem. :)

Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: Tried them both (with wine 1.7.8 instead). It still fails with the same error.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: it happens because of the installation of some i386 packages of wine.. I suggest you some links to follow, hope they might sort you problem. 1.[Link 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/323319/install-wine1-6-amd64-from-ubuntu-wine-ppa-asked-for-installing-wine1-6-i386-as) 2.[Link 2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit) 3.[Why do I get an “unmet dependencies” error when trying to install WINE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138530/why-do-i-get-an-unmet-dependencies-error-when-trying-to-install-wine/190424#190424)