# Errors when installing wine in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine, dependencies

I have followed the below procedures to install `wine` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
apt-get update 
apt-get install -y wine
```

---

However, I see the below error messages:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed

 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

---

After I did a check on the system, `unity-control-center` has already been installed. And I encounter the same error message when trying to install `wine1.6`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

============

## updated

According to A.B.'s suggestions, these are the outputs:

`lsb_release -a`

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core- 3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux yiliang-PORTEGE-Z930 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcheese-gtk23 is already the newest version.
libcheese7 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

`apt-get install wine1.8`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.8 : Depends: wine1.8-i386 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output of

```
apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine 1.8 unity-control-center libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
```

is very long and can be accessed from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4252202/apt-cache_policy.output).

```
wine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

wine1.6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

wine1.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

unity-control-center:
  Installed: 14.04.3+14.04.20150916-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 14.04.3+14.04.20150916-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 14.04.3+14.04.20150916-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     14.04.3+14.04.20140410-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

libcheese-gtk23:
  Installed: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

libcheese7:
  Installed: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

wine1.8-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean` and then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: The problem still exists after doing all these.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine 1.8 unity-control-center libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7; sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7; sudo apt-get install wine1.8`

Comment: A strange thing is, that `wine1.8-i386` isn't available (output of `apt-cache policy`). Please run `sudo apt-get update` and add the full output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link. After that, run `apt-cache policy wine1.8-i386` again give me the output, too. Leave a comment with `@A.B.`

Comment: @A.B.   The output of apt-get update can be accessed: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14464204/

Comment: @A.B. The output of apt-cachepolicy is here:    http://paste.ubuntu.com/14464236/

Comment: The good thing, `wine1.8-386` is now shown in the output of `apt-cache policy`. The bad, you have some errors during the `sudo apt-get update`. Let's try to correct this using the main server for the repositories with the following commands. `sudo sed -i 's|://sg\.|://|' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update` and give me the output.

Comment: @A.B. The output is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14468587/. There is no error this time.

Comment: @A.B. Then I try to install wine1.8 again:  and get the same error message : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14468606/

Comment: Let's continue with: `sudo apt-get install wine1.8-i386=1.8.0-0ubuntu1` and again the output please.

Comment: @A.B.  The output is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14473128/

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable 32-bit support within apt on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit in order to successfully install wine:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Why? I have installed it on 64-bit system without enabling 322-bit support. What is the basis of your answer?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha: On Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, the `wine` package via the OP's `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` includes the `wine1.8-i386` package as a dependency which apt-get does not permit as it's a x86 32-bit package. I was able to reproduce this issue and the above worked.

This [link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages) lists the dependencies for `wine1.8`:

`Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.17), wine1.8-amd64 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1), binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2), procps, wine1.8-i386 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1)`

Comment: Another very [similar issue & answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/654673/548677)

Answer (score -2):

you can try the following first:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then,

To install Wine, open the terminal by hitting ‘CTRL + ALT + T‘ from the desktop and run the following commands one-by-one on the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However,  the problem still exists.  Actually, there is are some warnings when I do: apt-get update

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Now when installing wine1.8, it complains:  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.8 : Depends: wine1.8-i386 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: But when I try to install wine1.8-i386, it complains about some more packages that are not installed...

Comment: Why would your answer help? Everything in your answer would lead to the same error messages.

Answer (score -3):

open the Terminal and execute the command one by one:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine
```

hope this command is useful

Comment: As it stands, this list of commands is useless. The last command is incomplete, the update command has already just been run according to the question, and I doubt the others will help anything in this situation. Please elaborate your answer and complete the commands and explain why this should solve the problem.