# Wine on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I have updated my OS from 14.04 to 15.10 (Both AMD64). In the past, wine installs without any problem on 14.04 machines, but this time there are problems.

I tried to install wine(Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer meta-package) directly from Ubuntu Software Centre. However, it tells me that package dependencies cannot be resolved with the following information:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine:
```

Then, I tried to install it using command lines. `sudo apt-get install wine` This time it says

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
             wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
```

Installing one of these packages bring out more unmet dependencies. I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` but it fails since `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.` Updating gives `The following packages have been kept back: libgbm1`. Removing `libgbm1` does not seem to work.

Other methods that I have tried but failed:
[Install wine1.6-amd64 from ubuntu-wine ppa asked for installing wine1.6-i386 as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323319/install-wine1-6-amd64-from-ubuntu-wine-ppa-asked-for-installing-wine1-6-i386-as)

`sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade` fails since it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

Comment: I believe you need to run `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 It says `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu10)`

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have the `i386` architecture. `update` is ` Unable to connect to archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006:` and failed to fetch packages from the same site. `sudo apt-get install -f` fails since it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.` Finally, `sudo apt-get install wine1.6` gives the same result as above.

Comment: You have Ubuntu Kylin?

Comment: @Zacharee1 No. I use the Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and then updated to 15.10.

Comment: So why do you have an Ubuntu Kylin archive PPA?

Comment: @Zacharee1 From attempting various methods to solve this problem. Do I need to remove it?

Comment: Yes. Remove any non-default sources you have.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Now I only have `http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu` and `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu` enabled. Is this enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37240/discussion-between-henry-w-and-zacharee1).

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks. I reinstalled Ubuntu and all errors are gone.