# Wine is not installing missing dependencies

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, wine, dependencies

I am getting really frustrated. I have been at this for a few hours now. I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 14.04. I am following the directions provided by this site:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/install-wine-1-8-stable-new-ppa/

[Installing Wine on 64 Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit)

and nothing is working. I am constantly getting the error the following dependencies have not been met. And the really frustrating part is that Ubuntu is not downloading and installing the dependencies. The message then goes on to list that I need to install wine 1.6 or 1.8.

Which I type `sudo apt-get install wine1.8` and that has missing dependencies. I then try to install those dependencies and I get the same error message. I install `wine-mono`, `winetricks`, and `wine-gecko` without any issue. I ran  `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and I am constantly receiving the error. Has anyone else ran into the issue before? Any help on the matter will be much appreciated.

I apologize if I am conveying too much frustration in the post. But it is a little annoying that I am spending hours on something so simple that should be `sudo apt-get install wine1.8`.

Here is my output from the command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.8 : Depends: wine1.8-i386 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1)
```

Comment: Is wine1.8 available for 14,04?

Comment: @Anwar it should be. I installed and had wine 1.8 working in 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a day and blowing off some steam, I have some good news to report. Interestingly, all the computer needed to do was a simple reboot. And everything started working again.

Even to to this day, I am still amazed at how computers work.

I guess when in doubt, restart the machine?

Thank you all for your answers. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Can you install a new package now?

Comment: Yes, I was able to install wine 1.8 without any issue. Quite interesting I must say. I guess whenever things are not simply making any sense, just do a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get install -f`. This command fixes dependencies. After fixing dependencies, continue according to the tutorial.

Comment: I have never actually seen this work.

Comment: Maybe you were unlucky but for me it helped me a ton of times.

Comment: Yes, I tried running this command and it did not install any of the missing dependicies.