# Wine & Bit Che software

Tags: software-installation

Following [Installing Wine on 64 Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214181/installing-wine-on-64-bit), I got the Terminal warning:
<!!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!>
So, how to properly install Wine & Bit Che applications on Ubuntu 21.04 via Terminal? Thanks

Comment: WINE has their own repository and installation instructions - https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I tried and got: <The following packages have unmet dependencies. winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 6.16~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.>

Comment: Make sure you uninstall ALL wine versions already on your system and remove that repository you added.  THEN try to install.  You have to remove all traces of the original Wine binaries that you had installed from the repos for the WineHQ ones to work

Comment: Actually, none installed, all failed. But some repositories might remain. Could you please advise me as for concise command to clean up?

Comment: without knowing which repositories you installed, etc initially it's not going to be straightforward to clean up.  Usually though I use `apt purge` to remove all traces of the packages when handling Wine to start with. `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` will remove the Wine repos you had used and are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. Terminal advised: <wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'>

Comment: All the above was followed & done more than once, including the way recommended by https://www.winehq.org/. However, <The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.> Does it mean that Wine cannot be installed on my 21.04?